# on click event modal doesn't stay open

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, bootstrap-modal

I have attached an onclick event on my glyphicon pencil icon provide by bootstrap, which then should fire up a modal popup.  This happens however it seems to close the modal straight after I click on the pencil.

```
$('.overlayed').on('click', '.glyphicon-pencil', function (e) {
    //hold the overlayed element for later use
    var chartID = $(this).parent().prev().prop('id');;

    $('#editWidgetModal').modal('toggle');

    //check for onclick event for the save button
    $('#edit-widget').on('click', null, function (event) {

        //Now assign all textboxes and create an object to pass into the lineBasedChart mutator
        var chartEditOptions = {
            title: $('#chart-title').val(),
            subtitle: $('#chart-subtitle').val(),
            yAxis: $('#chart-yAxis').val(),
            tooltip: $('#chart-tooltip').val(),
            lineWidth: $('#chart-lineWidth').val() == "" ? "" : parseInt($('#chart-lineWidth').val()),
            timeWindow: $('#chart-timeWindow').val() == "" ? "" : parseInt($('#chart-timeWindow').val()),
            refreshCycle: $('#chart-refreshCycle').val() == "" ? "" : parseInt($('#chart-refreshCycle').val())
        };

        //set renderTo data attribute to the widgets created element

        //overlayedData.data("data-render", chartID);
        chart[chartID].SetNewOptions(chartEditOptions);
        $('#editWidgetModal').modal('hide');

    });
});
```

Comment: Try just sticking an e.stopPropagation() after the first line. Because presumably $('#edit-widget').on is receiving the same click, which hides the modal at the end

Comment: @mwarren Edit widget is the submit button on the modal, which I have overridden.  I just stuck a breakpoint in it and it is running that piece of code twice, which hits toggle twice which is why it closes, but not sure how to solve it

Comment: I believe I was reattaching the event more times than necessary

Comment: Not solving your problem, but you have a double semi colon (`;;`) at row three.

Comment: Again maybe not related to your problem, but why do you set the click handler for `#edit-widget` in the click handler for `.overlayed`? Every time the user clicks `.overlayed` `#edit-widget` will get the same function added as a click even handler once more. This would make sense if you loaded `#edit-widget` dynamically so it was recreated every click, but I see no hints of that in your code.

Comment: I can only think that you've added the .overlayed class to more than one element.

Comment: @mwarren I have added the overlayed class to more than one element, each widget on my dashboard has an overlayed class

Comment: Makes sense. Forgive me for trying to rule out the obvious. So lots of elements with .overlayed class horizontally is fine, I was meaning vertically, inside a top element already with an .overlayed class.